# Grep command in array

Tags: bash

For a homework assignment I have to Take the results from the grep command, and write out up to the first 5 of them, numbering them from 1 to 5. (Print the number, then a space, then the line from grep.) If there are no lines, print a message saying so. So far I managed to store the grep command in an array but this is where I've gotten stuck: Can anyone provide guidance as to how to proceed in printing this as stated above

```
pattern="*.c"
fileList=$(grep -l "main" $pattern)
IFS=$"\n"

declare -a array
array=$fileList

for x in "${array[@]}"; do
echo "$x"
done
```

Comment: I would just use `grep -l main ${pattern} | head -5 | nl`...

Answer (score 0):

If you're only allowed to use `grep` and `bash`(?):

```
pattern="*.c"
fileList=($(grep -l "main" $pattern))

if test ${#fileList[@]} = 0 ; then
    echo "No results"
else
    n=0
    while test $n -lt ${#fileList[@]} -a $n -lt 5 ; do
        i=$n
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
        echo "$n ${fileList[$i]}"
    done
fi
```

If you are allowed to use commands in addition to grep, you can pipe the results through `nl` to add line numbers, then `head` to limit the results to the first 5 lines, then a second `grep` to test if there were any lines.  For example:

```
if ! grep -l "main" $pattern | \
    nl -s ' ' | sed -e 's/^ *//' | \
    head -n 5 | grep '' ; then
    echo "No results"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

you can grep options **-c** and **-l**

```
pattern="*.c"
searchPattern="main"

counter=1
while read -r line ; do
    IFS=':' read -r -a lineInfo <<< "$line"
    if [[ $counter > 5 ]]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    if [[ ${lineInfo[1]} > 0 ]]; then
        numsOfLine=""
        while read -r fileline ; do
            IFS=':' read -r -a fileLineInfo <<< "$fileline"
            numsOfLine="$numsOfLine ${fileLineInfo[0]} "
        done < <(grep -n $searchPattern ${lineInfo[0]})
        echo "$counter ${lineInfo[0]} match on lines: $numsOfLine"
        let "counter += 1"
    else
        echo "${lineInfo[0]} no match lines"
    fi
done < <(grep -c $searchPattern $pattern)
```